# HTML file fails to respond in Express app

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack

I am trying to set up an express app on a windows machine. A back-end file server.js in a directory called "server" responds to an angularjs file app.js in a directory called "public" and the display file index.html also in public displays the results. I have installed node, mongo, mongoose, express and angularjs. The index file is supposed to display a mongodb product I installed but it displays nothing.

the code from the three files
public/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app = "jetbrains" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat = "product in app.products">
            {{ product.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src = "app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

public/app.js

```js
var jetbrains = angular.module("jetbrains",[]);

jetbrains.controller("AppCtrl", function (shttp) {
    var app = this;
    shttp.get("http://localhost:3000").success(function (products) {
        app.products = products;
    })
})
```

server/server.js

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/localhost');

var Product = mongoose.model('Product',{name:String});

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    Product.find(function (err, products) {
        res.send(products);
    })
})

app.listen(3000);
```

The whole project is stored in a single directory and I'm using the webstorm ide to run the whole thing. Can anyone tell me why my index.html is displaying a blank page?

Comment: `shttp` should be `$http`, probably that might be typo..

Comment: that solved all my problems, thank you Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

i think you using **Directive Controllers (ng-conrtoller="AppCtrl as app")**, so that your app.js in think your code is not right. You can see this video is simple example about Directive Controllers. Hope this helpful =):
http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/4/section/2/video/1